# Upload and Retrieve PDF file to PostgreSQL using Node.js, Express and Knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

I am trying to upload and retrieve a PDF file to and from a PostgreSQL Db using Node.js, Express and Knex.

The DB column documentfile is file type Bytea.

The file seems to be uploading to the DB and is returned. The resulting PDF file (test3.pdf) does not want to open. I have been struggling with this for a long time now.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Node.js code to upload the file :

```
app.get('/uploadfile', (req,res) =>{
     fs.readFile('0203.pdf' function(err, imgData) {
        console.log(imgData)
        knex('documenttable').insert(
           {documentname: '0203.pdf',
            documentfile: [imgData]
          })
          .then( function (result) {
                res.end(console.log("Document uploaded To DB"));
        });
    }); 
});
```

Node.js code to retrieve the file:

```
app.get('/dbfileback', function(req, res, next) {
  knex('documenttable').where({
      documentnumber: '1'
    }).select('documentname', 'documentfile')
      .then( function (result) {
          fs.writeFile('test3.pdf', result[0].documentfile,'binary');
          res.end(console.log("Done"));
        });
  });
```

Comment: You are using the `fs` module, which interacts with the systems file system (hence the name). So you're actually writing a file to your server's harddrive.

You need to write the binary data to `res` instead.

Comment: Hi Lucas.  Thanks for your reply!  I am aware of this.  The PDF file does get written to the server hard drive. It is that PDF file that does not  want to open once it is written.

Comment: Oh, I see. So that is intentional for testing purposes. In that case, I would assume it is some kind of issue with data conversion between your code, knex and the database driver `pg`. Did you make sure that `result[0].documentfile` is actually a raw `Buffer`? AFAIK `pg` returns backslash-escaped strings for binary data.

Comment: console.log(' result[0].documentfile') returns:
<Buffer 7b 5c 78 32 35 35 30 34 34 34 36 32 64 33 31 32 65 33 36 30 64 32 35 65 32 65 33 63 66 64 33 30 64 30 61 33 31 33 32 32 30 33 30 32 30 36 66 36 32 36 ... >

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. The only other thing I noticed is that, when called with three arguments, `fs.writeFile` expects the third one to be the callback function.
But the encoding option is ignored anyways, since you're passing a `Buffer`.